# VS2019 Using a static library with iOS project

Tags: c++, ios, static-libraries, visual-studio-2019

Trying to port an example project for a product that uses a static library for iOS 13.2. The library is an "SDK" with the headers and .a and built singularly for "ARM64 Release" for the iPad. The original project, written for iOS 8.1 with VS2017, simply used -llibSomething.a in the "Additional Options" field and that worked. When doing the same in VS2019, the mac reports back that the linker option is ignored and fails to include it in the command that actually builds the application resulting in missing symbols. For the C++ application settings, there are no express linker options in the property page for the project unless I'm missing something--I'm not a big visual studio or iOS person. I know the path to the SDK is correct, the project finds the headers and compiles the sources without any undefined symbols, it just won't seem to link in the library. The biggest issue is that this all has to be done with whatever Visual Studio has to offer. Am I missing a dialog where this reference is supposed to go or is there something in the project.pbxproj that I'm supposed to be modifying?

Answer (score 0):

Wound up answering my own question:

- Unload the project
- Edit the project.pbxproj
- In the XCBuildConfiguration area for your configuration, add an entry for `OTHER_LDFLAGS = "-lSomething ";`

The list is just space separated, same as on the command line